# Why am I getting "[Errno 13] Permission denied" when trying to create a tensorflow environment in Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm trying to install TensorFlow 2.1 into its own Python 3.7 environment using Anaconda Prompt on a Windows 10 machine. I get an error saying `[Errno 13] Permission denied:` when I run the code to create the environment:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu python=3.7
```

I was able to create environments like this earlier tonight, only a few hours ago, but I could not get them to work with Jupyter Notebook so I deleted a few of them. All I have left is my base environment running Python 3.8, and another environment running Python 3.7 which I use for a project I'm working on. I need to create a tensorflow environment for another project but I can't create any environments anymore.

I ran `conda clean --all`. I tried running the Anaconda Prompt as an administrator. I tried restarting the system. I even uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it fresh (saving my project environment). None of this worked.

I can't even create an environment in Anaconda Navigator now. It just creates an empty environment folder inside the `anaconda3\envs` folder.

I can't think of any change I made which would have caused this problem, but it's possible I changed something in the environment variables earlier when I was trying to sort out the problem with Jupyter Notebook. It had been giving me weird messages and wouldn't let me open a notebook or use `pip install` at one stage, so I tried adding them to the path. I removed them again later when I reinstalled Anaconda.

Can anyone help me fix this problem so I can create new environments again?

Here is the full traceback:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda create -n tf-gpu python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.3
  latest version: 4.8.5

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Adrian\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.7


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2020.7.22-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2020.6.20-py37_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-20.2.2-py37_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.9-h60c2a47_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-49.6.0-py37_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.33.0-h2a8f88b_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_3
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.35.1-py_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_4


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python-3.7.9-h60c2a47_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf-gpu\\python.exe'
()
```

Comment: _It had been giving me weird messages and wouldn't let me open a notebook or use pip install at one stage, so I tried adding them to the path. I removed them again later when I reinstalled Anaconda._ There could be a bunch of issues here, you should consider removing all trace of Conda, and installing it again.

Comment: I completely reinstalled Anaconda, restarted the machine, and was able to create environments again. I created one, and a kernel for it, pip installed tensorflow and it's working as long as I don't open a Jupyter Notebook. What I find is every time I try to open a Jupyter Notebook from any environment other than base, it will open at first, but when I try to open a new .ipynb file I get an error message. After that I can no longer open Notebooks and the python.exe file associated with that environment goes missing.

Comment: Why use pip to install tensorflow? _when I try to open a new .ipynb file I get an error message._ The same _[Errno 13] Permission denied_ ?

Comment: At the moment pip seems to be the only way to install the latest version of tensorflow (which defaults to using the GPU). If I use Conda to install I think I have to specify tensorflow vs tensorflow-gpu. This may have changed, but pip definitely isn't the issue here because the same problem occurs even without tensorflow installed at all. It's got something to do with trying to open the notebook from an environment on Windows 10 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Going through this pain just now as well with all similar errors. Currently following this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnK1jO2kXOQ) tutorial with these (https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-jul-2020.ipynb) install instructions which seem promising.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the version of tensorflow, it sounds like the Conda installation is broken.

Comment: I had originally followed this tutorial to create a tensorflow-gpu enviornment using my original install of Anaconda (base environment using Python 3.7): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc&t=193s&ab_channel=thehardwareguy This worked. The issues started when I tried to follow this more recent tutorial to get a newer version of tensorflow which defaults to GPU: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IubEtS2JAiY&ab_channel=deeplizard In this second tutorial it seems to recommend installing it in your base environment. I instead tried to create an environment for it as per the first tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment.

I followed this tutorial with these install instructions and managed to get it working but had to **downgrade by base Python environment to 3.7**. If I didn't do this I got the same errors. Before starting this I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda.

Comment: I started getting these errors with a base environment of 3.7. In the course of trying to solve the issue I removed and reinstalled Anaconda, and with it updated my base environment to 3.8. Are you recommending I uninstall Anaconda again, and install an older version of it, then follow this tutorial?